# How to do doxygen documentation?

Tags: linux, documentation

My boss told me do documentation in `doxygen`. i did google and found you can do `codes` documentation in doxygen, but what about Details and text documentation which doesn't has codes.

Comment: What are you documenting ? Can you show us an example ?

Comment: its simple documents about, how to install `XYZ` application, for example lets say `How to install apache and configure SSL?` just need to do that kind of documentation. it has configuration file httpd.conf and ssl.conf how do i put them in doxygen?

Comment: You will be better off downloading doxygen manual and get an idea on how to document.  I do not think you should be using doxygen to write about how to install apache or configure SSL.

Answer (score 1):

First, install doxygen (I'm sure your OS distribution has a package).  Then, in the top directory of your source tree run:

```
doxywizard Doxyfile
```

This gives you an easy way to create a Doxyfile, which is essentially a set of instructions about how you would like doxygen to proceed.  I like to configure it to output to a subdirectory like `doc/html`.

Then put some doxygen comments in your source code.  You have to comment the top of the file with something like:

```
//! \file myfile.h This is my header file
```

And then comment individual symbols with:

```
//! This is my function:
void function();
```

There are other syntaxes, described here:  http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock

Then run:

```
doxygen
```

And it will create your documentation.  Fire up a web browser.

Oh, and if you want documentation files that don't contain source code, no problem.  You can configure doxygen to recognize markdown files that end `.md`.  Just make sure `*.md` is in your FILE_PATTERNS.  You can also set USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE to a markdown file to create the front page from markdown.  These directives are in your Doxyfile, but you can edit them from the wizard as well.